# Why ColorRect break Area2d?

Tags: godot, gdscript

ColorRect break Area2d

My scene:

```
root
└ Node2D
  └ Area2D
    ├ Sprite
    └ CollisionShape2D
```

Area2D.gd:

```
extends Area2D

func _ready():
    var b = self.connect("input_event", self, "_on_Area2D_input_event")
    print($"../..".print_tree_pretty())


func _on_Area2D_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if InputEventMouseButton and event.is_pressed():
        print("Click")
```

**Everything works**. If you click on the sprite, it is written "Click".

If my scene:

```
root
└ Node2D
  ├ ColorRect #This background
  └ Area2D
    ├ Sprite
    └ CollisionShape2D
```

The script Area2D.gd is breaking! If you click on a sprite, "Click" is **not **written.
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Control`s (such as `ColorRect`) take priority to handle input. So a `Control` will have an opportunity to handle the mouse input before any `Node2D` (such as `Area2D`) even if the `Node2D` is in front.

To fix that, change the Mouse Filter (`mouse_filter`) property of the `ColorRect` to "Ignore" (`MOUSE_FILTER_IGNORE`), so it does not handle mouse input, and lets the `Area2D` handle it.